# How do I pass a user in a POST request to a django view?

Tags: django, request, user-registration

I have a view `AccountRegister` that creates a new user. Every time I enter values into the Registration Form, a verification email is sent to the user if a user has registered with email, and verification token is sent to the user if a user has registered with a phone, and both if a user has registered with both. After successful registration, User is redirected to a Token Verification Page. To verify a token, I need to access the user from `TokenVerificationView`. How do I send user via request? How do I access the same user from `TokenVerificationView`?

```
class AccountRegister(CreateView):
model = User
form_class = forms.RegisterForm
template_name = 'account/signup.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('account:verification')

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.user = form.save(self.request)
    if self.user.email:
        send_email_confirmation(self.request, self.user)
    if self.user.phone:
        device = self.user.verificationdevice_set.create(
            unverified_phone=self.user.phone)
        device.generate_challenge()
        message = _("Verification Token sent to {phone}")
        message = message.format(phone=self.user.phone)
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, message)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: You are sending a verification email right, does the verification email contain any link to the token verification page??

Comment: Verification Page will simply inform the user that
"Your user account has been created. You must have a received a text or email to activate your account. If you registered with email, click on the verification link sent to your email. If you registered with phone, enter the token below. Token _________ [Verify Token]."
I need to access user from the `TokenVerificationView` to verify the token. 
And No, verification email doesn't contain any link to the token verification page.